# How to convert this sentence into passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

Sentence:

> The carrier requires the manufacturer to install the software code on the iPhone.

I want to convert the previous sentence into passive voice by making *software code* to be subject, but not sure I am doing correctly

Passive sentence:

> The software code is installed on the iPhone by the manufacturer as required by the carrier.

Did I change the meaning of the original sentence in the passive sentence?

Comment: I find it peculiar that you should want to transform a perfectly sensible, straightforward active construction into an inelegant and awkward passive construction.

Comment: Yes, you changed the meaning. Look closely at what you wrote. The original sentence was a statement of what was required and by whom it was required. Nothing was said about the installation actually having been accomplished. Your proposed sentence is a statement that it was accomplished and why. Also see my suggestion in the comments below. Moreover, I too am curious as to why you would want to change the original statement, unless simply as an intellectual exercise. It is certainly the simplest, the most elegant, and the clearest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The software code shall be installed on the iPhone by the (iPhone) manufacturer, to comply with carrier's requirements*.

Or

*The software code shall be installed on the iPhone by the (iPhone) manufacturer, as required by the carrier*.

Comment: can i change like this "The software code shall be installed on the iPhone by the iPhone manufacturer, which was required by the carrier."

Comment: yes the 2nd one is the most elegant, thax u for that

Answer (score 1):

The software code can only be installed by the iPhone manufacturer, per carrier requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my simple, logical passive-voice version of the sentence where the subject in the original sentence (carrier) becomes part of the predicate and the object (manufacturer) of the verb (requires) becomes the subject.

"The manufacturer is required by the carrier to install the software code on the iPhone."

As for your question, "Did I change the meaning of the original sentence in the passive sentence?" I would say, No, because the essence is still there. But most conversions from active to passive voice usually merely makes the subject part the predicate, and the object of the verb as the subject. That being the case the focus is now on the subject "manufacturer."

In the other versions offered, the verb tense used has been changed:

Elian used "shall be" which is not consistent with the present tense of the original sentence.

MrsLannister used "can." MrsLannister constructed the passive voice to mean that "software code can **only be installed** by the iPhone manufacturer" which is nowhere to be found in your original sentence.

In the version of user82023, "carrier" is still the subject, so there seems to be no real change from active to passive.  Moreover, the essence (that the manufacturer is the **one directly required** by the carrier to install the software...) was lost.

Answer (score -1):

The carrier requires the software code *to be* installed by the manufacturer on the iPhone

Comment: can u make "software code" to become subject in the passive sentence?

Comment: I don't know if this is valid, as the subjunctive is falling out of use, but I would have said, "The carrier requires the software code *be* installed..." because of the word *required*.

Comment: **The software code is required by the carrier to be installed on the iPhone by the manufacturer.** I think that this changes the original sentence as little as possible while converting both the finite verb and the infinitive to the passive.

Answer (score -2):

The manufacturer is required by the the carrier to install the software code on the iPhone